# arrage `selectInput` and `pickerInput` inline on the same row

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

In the app below I want to place a `shinyWidgets::pickerInput` `inline` next to a `shiny::selectInput`. Two inputs of the same kind (either `pickerInput` or `selectInput`) can be placed on the same line just by wrapping them in a `div(style =  "inline-block")`. While the app below places the inputs on the same line / row they are not on the same level vertically. I looked at the DOM inspector but do not understand, why this is happening and how I can fix it. Any help appreciated.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(ui = dashboardPage(
  
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Test"), 
  
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  
  body = dashboardBody(
  
    div(style = "display: inline-block;",
      selectInput("test",
                  "Select Input",
                  choices = 1:3)
    ),
    
    div(style = "display: inline-block;",
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "somevalue",
        label = "A label",
        choices = c("a", "b")
      )
    )
  
  ) # close dashbaordBody
  ), # close dashboardPage

  server = function(input, output, session) {

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex`:

```
  body = dashboardBody(
    
    div(style = "display: flex;",
        
        selectInput("test",
                    "Select Input",
                    choices = 1:3),

        pickerInput(
          inputId = "somevalue",
          label = "A label",
          choices = c("a", "b")
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks very promising! Any idea why vertical alignment is broken when mixing both input types? Looking at the DOM I really don't understand whats causing the inputs to be off.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Sorry I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase?

Comment: `"display: inline-block;"` works when using two inputs of the same type. When mixing `selectInput` and `pickerInput` the vertical alignment is broken as shown in my post. Normally looking at the DOM inspector helps to understand why the inputs have a different vertical alignment, but in this case I have problems understanding what is causing the inputs to have a different vertical alignment.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't know.

Comment: Was this solved using HTML? Or is display:flex some shiny code?

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi It's standard CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to be an irritating problem as well.  The simplest solution I've found is to wrap both the controls in a `fluidRow` and each in its own `column`.  This usually works (and seems to in this case). If it doesn't, then I resort to tweaking CSS borders and/or padding settings, which is very unsatisfactory.

[image]

Adjust the separation of the controls by playing with the `width` setting of each column.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(ui = dashboardPage(
  
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Test"), 
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
        column(
          width=6,
          selectInput("test",
                    "Select Input",
                    choices = 1:3)
        ),
        column(
          width=6,
          pickerInput(
          inputId = "somevalue",
          label = "A label",
          choices = c("a", "b"))
        )
    )
  )
),

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
})
```

Comment: +1 for the fast answer, which solves the problem. However, I would like to refrain from wrapping each input in `column`, because I'd like to have the inputs in a row without unnecessary spaces in between. It would be great if a nice CSS solution existed to solve this problem.

Comment: Happy to help.  Try `width=4` rather than `width=6` to reduce the white space.   But I think @StephaneLaurent may have your ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
           wellPanel(
             selectInput("test",
                         "Select Input",
                         choices = 1:3)
             
           )       
    ),
    
    column(2,
           pickerInput(
             inputId = "somevalue",
             label = "A label",
             choices = c("a", "b"))
    )
  )
)
```

Read this for more info: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Limey above has already suggested to wrap the inputs in `column`. My comment there applies here as well.